# SQL. Find the customers who bought same brands and at-least 2 products in each brand

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count, db2

I have two tables :

```
Sales
columns:  (Sales_id, Date, Customer_id, Product_id, Purchase_amount):
Product 
columns:  (Product_id, Product_Name, Brand_id,Brand_name)
```

I have to write a query to find the customers who bought the brands 'X' and 'Y' (both) and at least 2 products of each brand. Is the following query correct? Any recommended changes?

```
SELECT S.Customer_id "Customer ID"
FROM Sales S LEFT JOIN Product P
ON S.Product_id = P.Product_id
AND P.Brand_Name IN ('X','Y')
GROUP BY S.Customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT S.Product_id)>=2 -----at least 2 products in each brand
 AND COUNT(S.Customer_id) =2 ---------------customers who bought both brands
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` window function to count the number of distinct brands and the number of distinct products of each brand that each customer has bought.
Then filter out the customers who haven't bought both brands and `GROUP BY` customer with a `HAVING` clause that filters out the customers who haven't bought at least 2 products of each brand.
Also your join should be an `INNER` join and not a `LEFT` join.

```
select t.customer_id "Customer ID" 
from (
  select s.customer_id,
    count(distinct p.brand_id) over (partition by s.customer_id) brands_counter,
    count(distinct p.product_id) over (partition by s.customer_id, p.brand_id) products_counter
  from sales s inner join product p
  on p.product_id = s.product_id
  where p.brand_name in ('X', 'Y')
) t
where t.brands_counter = 2
group by t.customer_id
having min(t.products_counter) >= 2
```

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Thanks. Also, thank you for suggesting the JOIN error in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your existing query, you can use the following `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING 
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'X' then S.product_id end) >= 2
    AND COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'Y' then S.product_id end) >= 2
```

This ensures that the customer bought at least two products in both brands. This implicitly guarantees that it placed ordered in both brands, so there is no need for additional logic for this.

You could also express this with `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
HAVING 
    AND MIN(CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'X' THEN S.product_id END)
        <> MAX(CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'X' then S.product_id end)
    AND MIN(CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'Y' THEN S.product_id END)
        <> MAX(CASE WHEN p.brand_name = 'Y' then S.product_id end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT Customer_id
FROM (SELECT S.Customer_id, S.Brand_Name, COUNT(DISTINCT S.Product_Id) as num_products
      FROM Sales S LEFT JOIN
           Product P
           ON S.Product_id = P.Product_id
      WHERE P.Brand_Name IN ('X', 'Y')
      GROUP BY S.Customer_id, S.Product_Id
     ) s
GROUP BY Customer_Id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 AND MIN(num_products) >= 2;
```

Comment: @Sharon . . . This seems like the simplest solution.